# After Join data repetation in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
table :First
..............................................................................
id | ros | table | column | stool | date | places|
..............................................................................
1   12  5   6   a   2017-07-17  goa  |
2   12  5   6   b   2017-07-17  delhi|
..............................................................................


table :second

..........................................................................
id  | ros | name | email | phone | stos|address |date |
....................................................................................................
5      12    and   and@her.com  394924673464    6  fddsfds  2017-07-03 |
6      12    her     her@and.com    84838593894     6  fdafdfd  2017-07-04  |
....................................................................................................


Query like I am Using:
SELECT `p`.* FROM `first` `p` LEFT JOIN `second` as `st` ON `st`.`ros`=`p`.`ros` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10;
```

My question is why it returns 4 rows instead of just 2?
its resturning 4 value without having in the table should i need to use distinct or group by for that ??

Comment: You're going to need to add another join condition to stop the duplication, but nothing in your tables is obvious to meet this requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query :

```
SELECT p.* FROM first as p LEFT JOIN second as st ON st.site_id=p.site_id group by p.id ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

It returning 4 columns Because your tables has duplicate `site_id`.

Change your query with this.This will return you only 2 rows.

```
SELECT `p`.* FROM `first` `p` LEFT JOIN `second` as `st` ON `st`.`site_id`=`p`.`site_id` GROUP BY p.id ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: @Arushi Welcome

Answer (score 1):

It return 4 rows because of all of the site_id in both table is 11. to make it two columns simply just add Group By in your sql statements.

Just Like :

```
SELECT `p`.* FROM `first` `p` LEFT JOIN `second` as `st` ON 
`st`.`site_id`=`p`.`site_id` GROUP BY `p`.`id` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question "Why" is : This is normal as you are joining on `site_id` and every row in your first table has 2 matching `site_id's` rows in the second table so 2 * 2 = 4

```
#first table
+-----+---------+
| id  | site_id |
+-----+---------+
| 31  |   11    |
+-----+---------+
| 32  |   11    |
+-----+---------+
# second table
+-----+---------+
| id  | site_id |
+-----+---------+
| 5   |   11    |
+-----+---------+
| 6   |   11    |
+-----+---------+
```

When you join 31 from the first table to the second table on `site_id` you will get 2 rows `(31 with 5, and 31 with 6)`

And when you join 32 from the first table to the second table on `site_id` you will get 2 rows `(32 with 5, and 32with 6)`

you need to group the result on the person as @Sonu Bamniya said